# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al minimizar el formulario me siga funcionando un dispositivo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

```
           BackgroundWorker SegundoPlano = new BackgroundWorker();
           SegundoPlano.DoWork += enOtroHiloHuella;
           SegundoPlano.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Ya intenté con BackgroundWorker y nada, también intenté con el Thread

```
 s = new Thread(IniciarCaptura);
            s.Start();
```

y ninguno me funciona. Sólo cuando le pongo punto de interrupción funciona pero al compilar normalmente no me funciona.

Este es el que hace funcionar al dispositivo (un lector de huella dactilar)

```
                 private DPFP.Template Template;
    private DPFP.Capture.Capture Captura;
    private DPFP.Verification.Verification verificador;

    Negocio.Huella obhuella = new Negocio.Huella();
    protected virtual void init()
    {
        try
        {
            Captura = new DPFP.Capture.Capture();
            if (Captura != null)
            {
                Captura.EventHandler = this;
                verificador = new DPFP.Verification.Verification();
                Template = new Template();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO SE PUDO INICIAR LA CAPTURA");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO SE PUDO INICIAR LA CAPTURA" + E.ToString());
        }
    }
    protected void IniciarCaptura()
    {
        if (Captura != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Captura.StartCapture();
            }
            catch (Exception t)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO SE PUDO INICIAR LA CAPTURA" + t.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    protected void PararCaptura()
    {
        if (Captura != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Captura.StopCapture();
            }
            catch (Exception t)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO SE PUDO DETENER LA CAPTURA" + t.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    private void PonerImagen(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
    protected Bitmap ConvertirSampleMapaBits(DPFP.Sample Sample)
    {
        DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion convetidor = new DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion();
        Bitmap MapaBits = null;
        convetidor.ConvertToPicture(Sample, ref MapaBits);
        return MapaBits;
    }
```

Comment: Probablemente lo mejor es que en lugar de usar una aplicación winforms crees un Windows Service

Answer (score 0):

Habría que ver que dispositivo es, la api que utiliza y los requerimientos de la api.

Igual si pones más código para ver como haces el "hook" hacia el dispositivo sería más fácil ayudarte. .

En vez de un servicio, puedes crear tu aplicación utilizando un ApplicationContext:

```
public class MyApp: ApplicationContext
{
    public MyApp() 
    {
        // inicializas todo, y creas los eventos hacia el dispositivo
        // también aquí creas y muestras la ventana
    }

    // aquí van los métodos y propiedades que necesites
}
```

. 
   . 
   .

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    MyApp MyApp = new MyApp();

    // en vez de pasar una instancia de la ventana, pasas una instancia de tu aplicación 
    Application.Run(context);
}
```

Comment: estoy usando este dispositivo [https://webobjects2.cdw.com/is/image/CDW/1640083?$product-main$]

Comment: ya edite y agregue mas codigo del que inicializa el dispositivo y es lo unico que me falta que siga funcionando al estar minimizado

Comment: Intenta modificar esta parte:

    Captura = new DPFP.Capture.Capture();

por:

    Captura = new DPFP.Capture.Capture();
    Captura.Priority = DPFPDevXLib.DPFPCapturePriorityEnum.CapturePriorityHigh;

Comment: como que cambiaria al modificar esa parte

Comment: te comento que no me reconoce DPFPDevXLib

Comment: Posiblemente sea otra versión de librería, yo lo vi aquí:  http://devportal.digitalpersona.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=1731